# Data display problem with r language in jupyter-notebook

Tags: r, dplyr, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

```
View(flights)
```

> Error in View(flights): 'View()' not yet supported in the Jupyter R
> kernel Traceback:
>
> 1. View(flights)
> 2. stop(sQuote("View()"), " not yet supported in the Jupyter R kernel")

I want to pull and display data in r language with jupyter-notebook, but I guess the notebook does not support opening all this data. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `View`-function is not base R, but rather comes with Rstudio. As an alternative, you can use `head` from base R or `glimpse` from the tidyverse.

Comment: Quick note: `View` is not an RStudio function but a `utils` function (base-R). Otherwise you are totally correct.

Comment: I can only view all of them in RStudio environment because of large size data. Thanks for a useful solution though.

Answer (score 0):

The `View()` command opens a new window to display the data, which is not possible inside a notebook.
Instead of using `View()` you can directly show the data using `flights` or something like `head(flights)`.

Comment: thanks, it's a notable solution but at the moment this is also not enough due to the data size. The best is like RStudio for now.